# How is it possible that $\int\frac{dy}{(1+y^2)(2+y)}$ = $\frac{1}{5}\int\frac{dy}{y+2}-\int\frac{ydy}{1+y^2}+\int\frac{2dy}{1+y^2} $?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

Suppose we have a fraction

$$I=\int\frac{dy}{(1+y^2)(2+y)}$$

How is it possible that

$$5I = \int\frac{dy}{y+2}-\int\frac{ydy}{1+y^2}+\int\frac{2dy}{1+y^2} ?$$

How are they using partial fractions to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the partial fraction decomposition on $\dfrac{1}{(1+y^2)(2+y)}$? What have you got?

Comment: How is it not possible? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting
$$\frac{1}{(1+y^2)(2+y)}=\frac{A}{y+2}+\frac{By+C}{1+y^2}$$
gives
$$1=A(1+y^2)+(y+2)(By+C),$$
i.e.
$$0y^2+0y+1=(A+B)y^2+(C+2B)y+A+2C$$
Then, solve the following system : 
$$0=A+B,\quad 0=C+2B,\quad 1=A+2C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1{y+2}-\frac{y}{1+y^2}+\frac2{1+y^2}&=\frac1{y+2}+\frac{2-y}{1+y^2}\\
&=\frac{(1+y^2)+(4-y^2)}{(y+2)(1+y^2)}\\
&=\frac5{(y+2)(1+y^2)}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Apparently the downvoter is a bit confused, since this calculation shows precisely how it is possible that $$5I = \int\frac{dy}{y+2}-\int\frac{ydy}{1+y^2}+\int\frac{2dy}{1+y^2}\;.$$